# When looping through all images, how to indicate the one which is current dealing with?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I would like to use VBA to change the width of the images on-by-one in the doc. I need to manually judge wether the current image should be changed or not with a yes-or-no message box when looping through.
The current code is listed below, it works, but the problem is that WORD does not indicate which image is the current one.
Thanks!

```vb
Sub change_images()
  Dim iShp As InlineShape
  For Each iShp In ActiveDocument.InlineShapes
    With iShp
      If .Type = wdInlineShapePicture Then
        iShp.Select
        CarryOn = MsgBox("Change current image?", vbYesNo, "")
        If CarryOn = vbYes Then
            .LockAspectRatio = msoTrue
            .Width = 28.345 * 12
        End If
      End If
    End With
  Next
End Sub
```

I tried to add a .Select before the MsgBox line, but the usually selection mark can not be viewed when the code is running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
iShp.Select
Application.ScreenRefresh
```

You can be solved by using ScreenRefresh method.